# Big-O for while loops with user input

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Suppose Module X requires p units of time to be executed, where p is a constant. Find the complexity of each of the following algorithm where n is the size of the input data and q is a positive integer greater than 1. What will be the time complexity?

```
set i = 1
   `while i ≤ n` 
      `Module X` 
      `i = q * i` 
    endwhile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(n)` where the base of the logarithmic function is `q`.

Hint: `i` increases exponentially.

Comment: can you explain a bit please? I am really confused

Comment: Suppose `q = 2`. Then in each iteration `i` grows as follows: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 .... So how many iterations till `i` gets to `n`? It's `log(n)` with base 2. All we are doing is swapping 2 with `q`.